# Power 60% globalpowertune

Tags: ethos

Someone mentioned some settings to set when mining in ethos. I have all of them but how do I set the "power at 60%" in the config?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do it for each card or global. See below. If you want 60 change to 20 to 60

globalpowertune 20